# "AS" syntax in sqlite throwing error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, coordinates

I am trying to query based on distance in an sqlite database using some math. Accuracy of the results isn't that important, so I have the following:

```
SELECT * AS distance FROM items ORDER BY ((location_lat-lat)*(location_lat-lat)) + ((location_lng - lng)*(location_lng - lng)) ASC
```

I tried this:

```
location_lat, location_lng = (x,y)

c.execute("SELECT * AS distance FROM items ORDER BY ((?-lat)*(?-lat)) + ((? - lng)*(? - lng)) ASC", (location_lat, location_lat, location_lng, location_lng,))
```

But this ends up giving me an error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "AS": syntax error
```

Is the statement not correct, or is it complaining about the parameterized inputs `?`? What did I do wrong?

Comment: * refers to all fields in a table.  Try using "Select columnName as distance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `SQL` syntax is wrong. Use instead:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ((location_lat-lat)*(location_lat-lat)) + ((location_lng - lng)*(location_lng - lng)) ASC
```

**Explanation:** Since `*` returns all the columns within your table and `AS` is used reference the column to display with result set. Your SQL engine can not map many columns into 1.

In case you want to fetch just one column, let's `retailer_items` as `items` then you may use the query as:

```
SELECT retailers_items AS items FROM items ORDER BY ((location_lat-lat)*(location_lat-lat)) + ((location_lng - lng)*(location_lng - lng)) ASC
```

OR, you may use `AS` to find `min`, `max`, `count`, etc of columns. For example:

```
SELECT count(items) FROM items ORDER BY ((location_lat-lat)*(location_lat-lat)) + ((location_lng - lng)*(location_lng - lng)) ASC
```